# Recursion solution for a number raised to an exponent

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Hey I have a problem were I have to solve x^n in a number of ways. One of them involves using a recursion formula and its giving me a hard time. So one of the ways I used recursion for x^n for n>=0

```
int power2(int base, int power){
    if (power == 0)
        return 1;
    else if ( power == 1)
        return base;
    else 
        return (base * power2(base, power - 1));
}
```

this makes sense to me So when i set X = 2 and N = 4, it is decreasing the power, which is acting as a counter, and doing 2x2 power raised to 3, 4*2, power raised to 2, 8 *2 = 16. Than the power is raised to 1, and I have a base case were if the power is raised to 1 it just returns base. However for my next one I have to solve it using three formulas.

- x<sup>0</sup> = 1
- x<sup>n</sup> if n is even = [x<sup>n/2</sup>]<sup>2</sup>
- x<sup>n</sup> if n is odd = x * [x<sup>n/2</sup>]<sup>2</sup>

So what I have so far is

```
int power3(int base, int power){
    if(power == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( power == 1)
        return base;
    // if power is even
    if (power % 2 == 0){
        return base*(power3(base,(power/2)));
    }
    // if power is odd
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So im just trying to get even numbers to work first, and when I set x=2 and n=4 it returns 8. Which makes sense to me, since when the power is 4/2 will only loop twice for being >1. So i really am trying to figure out a way to get this to loop one more time while staying true to the formula I was given.and when I added the odd base case now the program will work up untill n^5 but n^6 returns 32

Comment: Food for thought: are you sure you need a separate base case for `power == 1`?

Comment: No your right, I added the odd power formula. which should handle the power when it gets to one. However it only works until 2^6 for example

Answer (score 4):

You got a little problem with the interpretation of the formula.
`x^n if n is even = [x^n/2]2` doesn't mean:

```
base*(power3(base,(power/2))) //meaning x * [x^n/2]
```

rather you'd have

```
(power3(base,(power/2))) * 2
```

looking at your formula again it isn't correct even and should be `x^n if n is even = [x^n/2]^2`

so as code:

```
(power3(base,(power/2))) * (power3(base,(power/2)))
```

or:

```
(power3(base * base,(power/2)))
```

Your whole function should probably be like this:

```
int power3(int base, int power){
    if(power == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( power == 1) // you don't really need this case,
        return base;      // power == 0 is enough as base case
        // if power is even
    if (power % 2 == 0){
        return (power3(base * base,(power/2)));
    }
    // if power is odd
    else{
         return base * (power3(base * base,(power/2)));
    }
}
```

Ok, since you seem to still be confused with the odd powers.
Your `power` variable is `int` so you get integer division meaning 3/2 = 1 instead of 1.5 (everything behind the decimal point gets truncated).

Now lets look at the odd case in the function:

```
return base * (power3(base * base,(power/2)));
```

lets assume `base == 4` and `power == 5`

```
return 4 * (power3(4 * 4,(5/2))); // 5/2 evaluates to 2
```

is the same as saying `return 4 * (power3(4, 5 - 1))`
and then having return `(power3(4 * 4, 4 /2))` since we now got an even case.

We basically just do these 2 steps as 1. I think my explanation sounds a bit weird but hope it helps.

Comment: (power3(base,(power/2))) * 2  this seems to return 32 for when 2^8

Comment: Can be corrected by doing smt like int val = (power3(base,(power/2))), return val*val;

Comment: the problem is that isnt a recursive way to solve the problem.

Comment: @user3277338 why isn't it recursive?

Comment: I thought in order for something to be recursive, the problem has to get smaller and smaller untill u reach the base case.

Comment: @user3277338 it does. `return (power3(base * base,(power/2)));` passes `power/2` as the new `power` and therefore decreases the problem in half with every function call until it reaches the `power == 0` (or 1) base case you got

Comment: @user3277338: The input arguments to the recursive function calls need to go down so you know that they reach the base case eventually. On the other hand, you are allowed to do whatever you want with your actual calculations.

Comment: @user3277338 Got to say that that was a nice question to wake me up there. The wrong formula got me at first before I rechecked it.

Comment: Oh raphael I was talking about Pham's suggestion. The last edited function you posted works perfectly, I cant thank you enough. Though Im still kind of confused on how it works. so for example you plug in 2^6 it sees that it is a even value sets power to 3 dose 2x2=4. Then sees its an odd power and that is where i get confused. Dose base stay as 4? and how can it do 3/2. Since there is no if statement really for odd powers. Shouldnt it keep looping forever 3/2 =1.5/2=.75...

Comment: C++ does integer division and discards the remainder. So `3/2` evaluates to `1`. (If you want to get the remainder you can use the `%` operator)

Comment: @user3277338 I added a little explanation about the odd case just behind the full implementation of the function, hope that helps to understand it.

Comment: @user3277338 even my suggestion is still a recursive :)